# "Spoon feed" vs. "spoonfeed"

Tags: verbs, orthography, spacing

Is there a whitespace in *spoonfeed*? I have to choose between writing *Spoon Feed Code* and *Spoonfeed Code*.

Comment: Mightn't you also _spoon-feed_ code?

Comment: Based on [this list](http://www.onelook.com/?w=spoonfeed&ls=a) and [this list](http://www.onelook.com/?w=spoon+feed&ls=a), and [this Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=spoon+feed%2C+spoonfeed%2C+spoon-feed&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), I'd follow @Brian Hooper's suggestion, and use the hyphen.

Comment: What @J.R. said. Also consider the fact that Google Books records only three instances of [I spoonfed him](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I+spoonfed+him%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), as opposed to 185 instances of [I spoon fed him](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I+spoon+fed+him%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) GB treats hyphens as spaces, but if you look at the results you'll see the vast majority do in fact have ***spoon-fed***.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Mightn't you also *spoon-feed* code? @Brian Hooper

For AE and BE this seems to be the most common usage and the one I would also have suggested.

spoonfeed: 158,000, spoon feed: 696,000, spoon-feed: 699,000.